# How to Write An Instance Of an Added Element When Using array.splice()?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an instance of the elements that have been added using the `splice()` function.

```
var myFish = ['angels', 'clowns', 'starfish', 'sharks'];
var removed = myFish.splice(2,1, "spongebob"); 
console.log(removed); //
```

The output I'm looking for is `spongebob` but instead I get `starfish`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you trying to replace ````starfish```` with ````spongebob```` because if so, you did that successfully.  ````removed```` is showing the element that you ````spliced```` out of the ````array````.  If you actually ````console.log(myFish)````, you will see that your ````array```` now includes ````spongebob````.

Comment: Array.splice() will return the removed element.

Comment: It's called `removed` for a reason.

Comment: Why use `splice` in the first place if you don't want the removed item? Simply do: `var added = myFish[2] = "spongebob";`

Answer (score 2):

`Array.splice` returns the deleted elements, not the mutated array.

```js
var myFish = ['angels', 'clowns', 'starfish', 'sharks'];
console.log("Array before we splice: ", myFish);
var removed = myFish.splice(2,1, "spongebob");
console.log("Array after we splice: ", myFish);
console.log("Replaced Element ", removed, "with: ", myFish[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are splicing by index 2 (starfish), remove 1 element and replace with 'spongebob'. starfish is removed and stored in removed var.

```js
var myFish = ['angels', 'clowns', 'starfish', 'sharks'];
var removed = myFish.splice(2, 1, "spongebob");
console.log(myFish);  //["angels", "clowns", "spongebob", "sharks"]
console.log(myFish[2]); // spongebob
console.log(removed); // ["starfish"]
```

Comment: thanks man! haha sometimes i appear to overcomplicate things :)